# Zeppelin - How to give Permissions To Users

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When I am sharing the paragraph of a notebook to a user in Zeppelin. If he applies the filters to data, then other users also see that filtered data on their screen. So How can I enable the users for the concurrent access the same notebook/ paragraph without affecting others' operation on the same notebook?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called "Personalized Mode".
There is no documentation about it.

You could look at https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/1753 "[ZEPPELIN-1594] Support personalized mode"